# Omnipay migs integration

Tags: php, omnipay

Hello I'm using omnipay github lib with migs integration in my project. The sample code isn't seems to be working. Can anyone help me with this?

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \Omnipay\Omnipay as omnipay;

$gateway = Omnipay::create('Migs_ThreeParty');
$gateway->setMerchantId('foo');
$gateway->setMerchantAccessCode('foo');
$gateway->setSecureHash('foo');

try {
    $response = $gateway->purchase(array('amount' => '0.00', 'currency' => 'AED', 'returnURL' => 'www.google.com.pk'))->send();

    if ($response->isRedirect()) {
        // redirect to offsite payment gateway
        $response->redirect();
        //$url = $response->getRedirectUrl();
        //$data = $response->getRedirectData();

    } else {
        // payment failed: display message to customer
        echo $response->getMessage();
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // internal error, log exception and display a generic message to the customer
    exit('Sorry, there was an error processing your payment. Please try again later.');
}
```

Does "$gateway->setSecureHash" == "$SECURE_SECRET" as shown in the example link http://integrate-payment-gateway.blogspot.in/2012/01/migs-payment-gateway-integration-php.html

The above code is asking for the redirectUrl and the transactionId. Where to specify it?

Comment: What do you mean "the sample code doesn't seem to be working"? Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes php gives Fatal error and the message says to provide the returnURL. How can I provide it in the above example? Further more it also asked to provide the transactionId. I don't know where to find it and provide. And yes the sample code was taken from github.

Comment: I wouldn't use the $response->redirect() method. How you do a redirect depends on what framework you are using -- some of them prefer you create a redirect object and return that from your controller, some others implement it very differently. What I would do instead is to get the redirect URL using $response->getRedirectUrl() and redirect to that using your framework's usual method.

Comment: The question I have asked it that the code is not executing as it asks to provide the returnURL and transactionId. Can you provide any working sample of it?

Comment: No one here to help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \Omnipay\Omnipay as omnipay;

$gateway = Omnipay::create('Migs_ThreeParty');
$gateway->setMerchantId('MerchantId');
$gateway->setMerchantAccessCode('MerchantAccessCode');
$gateway->setSecureHash('SecureHash');

try {
    $response = $gateway->purchase(array(
        'amount' => '10.00', // amount should be greater than zero
        'currency' => 'AED',
        'transactionId' => 'refnodata', // replace this for your reference # such as invoice reference #
        'returnURL' => 'http://yourdomain.com/returnPage.php'))->send();

    if ($response->isRedirect()) {
        $url = $response->getRedirectUrl(); // do whatever with the return url
    } else {
        // payment failed: display message to customer
        echo $response->getMessage();
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // internal error, log exception and display a generic message to the customer
    echo $e;
    exit('Sorry, there was an error processing your payment. Please try again later.');
}
```

Comment: @Mohammad_Sharaf your solution works fine but in interface of mastercard, the amount is multiple by 100. Can you help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Try 'amount' => $amount * 100; as migs accepts integer amount.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, what is the returnURL about?
The answer is the difference between the Migs_TwoParty and Migs_ThreeParty methods.

The Migs_ThreeParty passes control to the payment provider and when the payment is processed control is passed back to your website.  The documentation puts it this way:

> The cardholder's Internet browser is redirected to take the
>   Transaction Request to the Payment Server to process the transaction.
>   After processing the transaction, the cardholder's Internet browser is
>   returned to a web page that you nominate in the transaction together
>   with a Transaction Response. The Transaction Response processing of
>   the receipt information completes the transaction.

If you want to do all of the interfacing with the Gateway yourself you should use the Migs_TwoParty method.  The returnURL is then not required.

Cheers
Murray

Comment: I agree. The code I have posted works in the case of 2 party where you need to provide returnUrl and transactionId. After struggling for lot of hours I managed to make the code work as expected. Thanks :-)

Comment: @MohammadSharafAli Can you share with us the final code result ... thnx

Comment: I only ever implemented the MIGS_TwoParty, and that code has now been replaced as we moved to Payway a few years back.

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad Sharaf Ali had resolved my all problem regarding the MiGS. Thank you Mohammad Sharaf Ali.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34533289)